# Navigating Windows 8 with an Xbox 360 controller

Tags: windows-8-preview, windows-8, xbox360

I'm planning on using Windows 8 for my HTPC. Is there some way of navigating the "Metro" Windows Start screen with an Xbox 360 controller via some setting or third-party software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new app called [XBStart](http://www.xbstart.info) which adds XBox 360 controller navigation to Windows 8 Start Screen. It also adds sound effects like in Xbox One.

Answer (score 1):

MS allows you to use the XBox 360 controller for games in Windows without issues.  However, I dont know if it will work on navigating the Modern UI.

However, if it does not work, there may be a workaround.  Here are some very detailed [directions](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-an-Xbox-360-controller-as-a-mouse/) on how to set up the controller as a mouse.  It uses a 3rd party software called [JoyToKey](http://joytokey.net/en/download) for mouse emulation.

Based on the screenshots and date of the article, this was done in Windows 7.  I dont see why it wouldnt work on Windows 8, but you would have to test it to be sure.