# How to navigate Windows 10 with an Xbox 360 Controller?

Tags: windows-10, xbox360, game-controller

Note: I have checked this question already [Navigating Windows 8 with an Xbox 360 controller](https://superuser.com/questions/476891/navigating-windows-8-with-an-xbox-360-controller) and Xbstart wouldn't work, and last time I went to JoyToKey website (could be a fake one) Chrome warned me that it has malicious software in it.

How to navigate Windows 10 with an Xbox 360 Controller? I want to navigate through my desktop, my Start menu, etc. Is there any ***reliable*** program that would let me do it?

Comment: You've tried any of these alternatives (http://alternativeto.net/software/joytokey/), right?

Comment: This is an official download page for Joy2Key: http://download.cnet.com/JoyToKey/3000-2094_4-75220348.html. I have never had any problems with it, and I know there are, indeed, fake Joy2Key sites out there.

Comment: Um... thanks even though I just found my alternative. Let me test it. Thanks @oldmud0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antimicro is a nice one, it is free and can be customized easily, even though you **can't navigate the start menu like an Xbox, but you can put a mouse option**.

You can download it here:
https://github.com/Ryochan7/antimicro/releases

Shoutout to @oldmud0 for letting me know with the alternativeto website.